# Adding content-id header in multipart entity

Tags: java, rest, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to send a multipart request using Java HttpClient and entity mime classes. The request would be like below:

```
POST /webservices/picture/7 HTTP/1.1
Host: abc.def
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=random_boundary_data;
 start="<49f75f79-c221-493c-a5f7-307c37f35828>"

--random_boundary_data
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <49f75f79-c221-493c-a5f7-307c37f35828>

{
    "type": "BASIC",
    "pictureId": {
        "uri": "cid:E6626568-4749-4FAC-85E0-B475C048FFB6"
    }
}
--random_boundary_data
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID: <E6626568-4749-4FAC-85E0-B475C048FFB6>

<<binary-image-data>>
--random_boundary_data
```

I am facing problem to set the Content-ID header in the entity using `MultipartEntityBuilder` .

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create()
                .addTextBody("pic_json", picObj.toJSONString(), ContentType.create("application/json"))
                .addBinaryBody("upload_file", upIcon, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), "filename")
                .build();


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://" + ipaddr + "/" + picUri);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related");
```

Comment: What your particular issue is?

Comment: The issue is that I find no way to add the Content-ID header in the entity.